# Symfony2 - Sonata & KnpMenu - setCurrentUri

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

So I want to install [Sonata Admin Bundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/installation.html) and [Sonata User Bundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html).
According to their page, AdminBundle [requires KNPMenuBundle in version 2.*](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/installation.html#enabling-sonataadminbundle-and-its-dependencies)
So my `composer.json` looks like this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "~3",
    "components/jquery": "dev-master",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.4.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^2.2"
},
```

And `AppKernel.php` like this

```
$bundles = [
    new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
    new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
    new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
    new My\ProductBundle\MyPdBundle(),
    new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
    new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
    new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
    new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
    new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
    new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
    new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),

    new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),
    new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
    ];
```

But when I try to visit `mypage.local/app_dev.php/profile` I've got this error:

```
Attempted to call method "setCurrentUri" on class "Knp\Menu\MenuItem".
Did you mean to call "setCurrent"?
500 Internal Server Error - UndefinedMethodException

in vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/Block/ProfileMenuBlockService.php at line 91
$menu->setCurrentUri($settings['current_uri']);
```

There is a lot of information in stack that `Sonata` requires `KnpMenuBundle` in version 1.3 but as I wrote, In `dev-master` bramch Sonata requires KnpMenuBndle in version 2.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out!

If you want to use Sonata AdminPanel & Sonada UserPanel (with FOSUserBundle) here is working configuration:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "~2.3@dev"
},
```

You can use 1.3 version of FOSUserBundle but it supports only SF2 in 2.1 version. FOS 1.3.* supports SF2 in 2.6 version.

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*@dev"
```